# spring native query call a function that returns a json

Tags: java, json, spring, postgresql, jdb

I am new to java and I am trying to call a function that returns a json object, However the java method returns a String.

Is there a way  in postrgres to convert Json to VARCHAR, or in java to vonvert JSONObject to a json String

```
@Repository
public interface CourseRepository extends JpaRepository<Course, Long> {
    @Query(value = "select* from get_enrolled_courses(:id);", nativeQuery = true)
    JSONObject getStudents(@Param("id") int courseId);


}
```

```
`    
@Service
public class CourseServices {
public JSONObject getEnrolledStudentsLight(int id){

        return repository.getStudents(id);
    }`
}
```

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v2/courses")
public class CourseController {
    @GetMapping ("/{courseId}/students/light")
    public String getEnrolledStudentsLight (@PathVariable int courseId ){
        return service.getEnrolledStudentsLight(courseId).toJSONString();
    }

}
```

I tried toJSONString() but the out put is key:value String and I only want the values as string just like the out put from the database

```
create or replace  FUNCTION get_enrolled_courses (student_id int)
    RETURNS  varchar
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
As $$
DECLARE s_id INTEGER;
begin
    select student_id into s_id;
    return (select COALESCE(array_to_json(array_agg(row_to_json(t)) ),'[]'::json)
            from (
                     select c.id,c.title,c.credits,c.updated_at,c.created_at
                     from course_student cs join courses c on c.id = cs.course_id
                     where cs.student_id = s_id
                 ) t);
end;
$$;
```

the output of the DB is : [
{
"id": 14,
"title": "Intoduction to computer scince",
"credits": 9,
"updated_at": "2023-05-05T20:56:58.160225",
"created_at": "2023-05-05T20:56:58.160225"
},
{
"id": 18,
"title": "Data Base 2",
"credits": 12,
"updated_at": "2023-05-05T20:57:20.064462",
"created_at": "2023-05-05T20:57:20.064462"
},
{
"id": 19,
"title": "Signal and Systems",
"credits": 9,
"updated_at": "2023-05-05T20:57:20.066494",
"created_at": "2023-05-05T20:57:20.066494"
}
]

any suggestions?

Comment: Could you elaborate on why exactly you need a string representation of students?

Comment: The idea is to send it back to the front end. What do you suggest

Answer (score 0):

1. I would try to create Entity aka. DBO for student instead of Returning JSONObject.
2. Use ObjectMapper that returns a string JSON representation.

   ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();   String studentsJSON
   = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(students);